# autoSignIn, logs in automatically as expected but app crashes when getting info from DB

Tags: android, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication

AutoSignIn Fucntion

```
private void getUser() {
    if (FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser() != null) {
        startActivity(new Intent(this, HomeActivity.class));
    } else {
        startActivity(new Intent(this, MainActivity.class));
    }
}
```

another way i tried storing the user in Common class by creating a static variable of the model class

```
    private void getUser() {
    if (Common.currentUser != null) {
        startActivity(new Intent(this, HomeActivity.class));
    } else {
        startActivity(new Intent(this, MainActivity.class));
    }
}
```

getting info from db

```
tvName.setText(Common.currentUser.getRiderName());
```

trying with firebase user

```
   tvName.setText(FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getcurrentUser.getDisplayName());
```

Comment: kindly post your logcat too, hence one can help you better

Comment: If the app crashes, there is a stack trace. Please look that up on logcat, and add it to your question. Please also responde witn @AlexMamo

Comment: @AlexMamo it says i'm trying to pass null variable by intoCommon.currentUser.getRiderName();

Comment: How is `Common.currentUser` declared?

Comment: I created a static variable of Rider in Common class as and every first time a user logsIn i pass the Rider class in to currentUser                                      
    `public class Common {

    public static Rider currentUser = new Rider();
}`

Comment: this is the assignment of rider to currentUser `Common.currentUser = rider;` when user logs in and it lets me access every attribute of class but on reopening the app and auto login it won't